# how to load a div depending on my url status in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video embed code on my site but sometimes the target url (video host) is down! in these moments my site waiting for connection in long time and at the end doesn't load video.. this is a bad experience!

I can load video from my host but for some reason I want embed that video. but I think I can check the target url with jquery if that was success then append embed code and otherwise append video in my host.

this is my embed code (code 1):

```
<div id="14750915864459730">
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.example.com/embed/dl4ue?data[rnddiv]=14750915864459730&data[responsive]=yes"></script>
</div>
```

this is my ownhosted video (code 2):

```
[video width="1920" height="1080" mp4="http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/americ.mp4"][/video]
```

both of codes are in html (on wp)

now I want something like this:

```
if https://www.example/... is reachable
then: load code 1
else: load code 2
```

also when url check is take more than 2 second just load code 2.

anyone can help?!

Answer (score 1):

You can ping server and use the result to see if server is available.
try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ping(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://www.example.com/embed/dl4ue?data[rnddiv]=14750915864459730&data[responsive]=yes",
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //server is NOT down. So embed your video
        // Code1 here
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert('POST failed.'); // server is down
         // Code2 here
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

EDIT: JQuery does not support cross domain ajax. So you can not Ajax to another domain. If you want `crossDomain` ajax permission you can use following `PHP` code(If your server side code is PHP):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

Comment: I can't solve XMLHttpRequest cannot load example.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ERROR

Comment: Also this function always return error (post failed) when use the internal page in my domain! this is other issue!

Comment: @nimasp This is the Cross-Origin problem we both mentioned in our answers. You should add either the PHP code from this answer or the linked JavaScript mod from my answer to fix this

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
  // This tries to access the external video
  url: 'https://www.example.com/embed/dl4ue?data[rnddiv]=14750915864459730&data[responsive]=yes',
  error: function(result) {
    // External video is not available, use this one instead:
    $('#14750915864459730').replaceWith('<video width="1920" height="1080" mp4="http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/americ.mp4">');
  },
  timeout: 2000 // Stops trying after 2 seconds
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="14750915864459730">
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.example.com/embed/dl4ue?data[rnddiv]=14750915864459730&data[responsive]=yes"></script>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: As Man Manam noticed, this problably won't work due to Cross-Origin issues. You can solve this by adjusting the server-side CORS configuration if you wish.

Alternatively, a JavaScript-only solution is to use this mod: https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js. Including this script will effectively solve the Cross-Origin problems.

Comment: This code does not work because JQuery does not allow Cross-Origin Request.

Comment: @ManManam You are right, thank you for noticing. As your answer already provided a server-side solution, I've added a client-side fix  in my answer for those who prefer that